# Tabs.url is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here!  This should be working I believe.  I'm writing a chrome extension and this should get the current tab's url and set the html of `#current-tab` to the url (for testing purposes).  The code successfully gets to the callback, but it says that tab.url is undefined when I put it in an alert box, and it does not put it's value in `#current-tab`.  Here's the code I have:

```
$('#get-tab').click(function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({"active" : true}, function(tab){
        for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            alert(tab[i].url);
            $('#current-tab').append(tab[i].url);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `tab[i].url`?

Comment: @Kiyura Ha, looks like we were thinking the same thing :)

Comment: I initially did that (`tab[i].url`) as I knew that it returned an array, but that didn't seem to be working either, so I posted the script that I was trying instead, which didn't make much sense to me, but I was experimenting...  See my edit above with my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong!  Apparently you need to reload the extension to refresh changes to the manifest file!  I had added the permissions later, but had not reloaded the extensions in the extension manager, so the change had not taken effect!  We're rolling now!

Comment: Haha, so it was the manifest, that's good! Was it the `tabs` part?

Comment: Same issue here. this show be on the front page of the google extension docs.

Comment: Thanks! I just solved my issue thanks to you :D

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.tabs.query` actually returns an array of `Tab` objects, so you would have to reference the tab inside of the array (even if it is only one `Tab`):

```
$('#get-tab').click(function(){
chrome.tabs.query({"active" : true}, function(tab){
    for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        alert(tab[i].url);
        $('#current-tab').append(tab[i].url);
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: I initially did that (`tab[i].url`) as I knew that it returned an array, but that didn't seem to be working either, so I posted the script that I was trying instead, which didn't make much sense to me, but I was experimenting...  See my edit above with my original code.

Comment: @Notionwork We'll go for the easy way first (hopefully :) ) - do you have `tabs` in your `permissions` in `manifest.json`?

Comment: Yup!  Here's my manifest: `{
 "name" : "Notionwork Site Manager",
 "version" : "1.0",
 "manifest_version" : 2,
 "description" : "The manager organizes sites that are of interest and adds corrisponding bookmarks to the Chrome bookmark manager",
 "browser_action" : {
  "default_icon" : "icon.png",
  "default_popup" : "popup.html"
 },
 "permissions" : [
  "tabs"
 ],
 "icons" : {
  "128" : "icon.png"
 }
}`

Comment: @Notionwork Alright, let's figure this thing out. Where are you defining your JavaScript? Is it directly inside of `popup.html`? One issue that comes up with manifest v2 is that you can no longer use in-line scripts, so if it is inside of there, try moving it into a `popup.js` as a background script that you call from `popup.html`.